# Pundit for complex authorization for models with join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization

I have a scenario where I have a bunch of objects called courses each with many lessons and each lesson with many sections.

I also have a fourth model called Track. Now I've created a join table for courses and tracks such that I can create a "path" to learn something e.g path to algbera would consits of the track and multiple algerba courses.

Now some of the courses are free, but some are not. To those courses that aren't free I would need to start building some kind of authorization. I'm using stripe's subscriptions to see wheter certain users can access certain courses.

It's the section models show action that I need to restrict since the user should be able to view the contents of the course just not able to "start" the course.

How should I approach this authorization here? I'm using pundit and I would probably need to set up some kind of policies such as

```rb
class SectionPolicy
    attr_reader :user, :section

    def initialize(user, section)
        @user = user
        @section = section
    end

    def show?
    end
end
```

but this feels like I'm doing something wrong as I would need to fetch the course from the section model i.e `section.lesson.course`.

Another probelm I'm facing is that say I have path A and path B, then each of these path's could share one or multiple courses, but they still would need different authorization as users who can access path A may not neccessarily access path B.

I suppose I need to add some kind of attributes to the course model to set the access for users with certain authorizations?

Comment: This isn't a bad question but its a question for a discussion forum and the Q&A format of Stackoverflow. Your pundit policies don't necessiary have to coincide with your actual models. You're authenticating *resources* which is a higher level concept. Models are just the actual internal implementention details.